# Is 2:1 Mux (Multiplexer) same as 2:1 Encoder, theoretically?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, multiplexer, digital-communications, encoder

I just came across a question states:

> A Combinational circuit which is used when it is desired to send data from 2 or more sources through a single transmission line is known as: ______

I know it is `2:1` Mux but the thing is can't it be `2:1` Encoder? I know there are 4 types of =Encoders but can it be possible theoretically?

Comment: A 2:1 mux has a total of three inputs including the select line, and one output. Does an encoder have similar number of inputs and outputs? If not, can it satisfy the requirement of sending two data lines over a single line? I think it would be clear if you drew the symbols of a mux and an encoder in the question showing the lines going into the device and lines coming out of the device.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a **multiplexer** to me.

Hover over the multiplexer tag below your question for an SE definition.

---

[TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/digital_circuits/digital_circuits_multiplexers.htm) has some good explanations of both:

[image]

> A **Multiplexer** is a combinational circuit that has maximum of 2n data inputs, ‘n’ selection lines and single output line. One of these data inputs will be connected to the output based on the values of selection lines.

This is fairly simple in your case. You'll only have I<sub>0</sub> and I<sub>1</sub> for the inputs and s<sub>0</sub> for the selection. We can see that this will work.

---

[image]

> An **Encoder** is a combinational circuit that performs the reverse operation of Decoder. It has maximum of 2n input lines and ‘n’ output lines. **It will produce a binary code equivalent to the input, which is active High**. Therefore, the encoder encodes 2n input lines with ‘n’ bits. It is optional to represent the enable signal in encoders.

The problem here is that the encoder is only expecting one input high at a time. Since your inputs are independent you can't guarantee that so output is probably undefined - and that's before you start trying to select which one to read.

I suspect that the answer to your question is "no" but I'll leave you to prove it to yourself.

Comment: That I know. All I want to ask is if we can use Encoder as a Multiplexer? Won't they be same same if Input have 2 lines?